# check if install sub folder still exist

Tags: codeigniter

I have an codeigniter install wizard directory as a sub folder that has 4 steps to complete before the user can access the site. So if the users server uploads it to their localhost or ftp it will get redirected to install index.php otherwise if the user completed all steps he gets access to the website.

But I can not seem to be able to make it work so once user has completed the steps that the block will be lifted and he'll be able to view website and work on it.

I have in my main index.php a function which checks if folder still there.

```
if (!defined('install')) {
header('Location: install/index.php');
exit;
}
```

Folder Structure

application folder

download folder

image folder

index.php

install folder

install / application folder

install / index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's file exists function to check whether the directory exists on not:

bool file_exists ( string $filename )

in $filename put the full path to the folder.

[Read about docs here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)